# Find Full Path by Folder Name for Folder in Another Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, path

In my web project solution I have numerous projects added in it.

I have folder names as 'Localization' in one of the project.

So by specifying folder name in code behind from another project, how do I get the full path of the folder.

If folder is present in one of the project then I need to get the full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this example, for get  the full path of another folder.

```
System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~"), "../Localization/"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You mention "if folder is present", so you will need to test to see if the folder is there first:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/FolderName"));
if (dir.Exists)
{
    //dir.FullName will get you the path.
    //This is the same things as Server.MapPath("~/FolderName"), but that
    //will return a path even if the folder isn't there.
}
else
{
    //folder doesn't exist.
}
```

Since you are trying to go outside your project, you can do something like this (depending on your solution structure):

```
string path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~"), @"..\OtherProjectName/FolderName")); 
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
```

Comment: Even in this case it is returning the path of the project even if folder is not present in it

Comment: `dir.Exists` will only be true if the directory is there. I can only assume you are passing the incorrect path. What are you using and what do you expect?

Comment: I have created folder in Project 1 and I am finding that folder from project 2. Like following.                                         Dim dir As System.IO.DirectoryInfo = New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Localization"))
        If dir.Exists Then
            str = dir.FullName
            Response.Write(str)
        End If

Comment: ...that's not even C#. Why is this tagged C#?

Comment: Apologize for that.. I forgot to paste in C#

Comment: Now how can i get the exact path ?

Comment: @Rohit I added an option. Hopefully that works for you. It works in testing.